# Unable to run the code on device

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I am trying to merge videos and the code is running fine on simulator. I am able to merge videos,
but when I run the same code on device it gives me this exception

**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '* -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil**

the code is here :

```
AVMutableComposition *mixComposition = [AVMutableComposition composition]; AVMutableCompositionTrack *compositionTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid]; NSError * error = nil; NSMutableArray * timeRanges = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:videoClipPaths.count]; NSMutableArray * tracks = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:videoClipPaths.count]; for (int i=0; i<[videoClipPaths count]; i++) { AVURLAsset *assetClip = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:[videoClipPaths objectAtIndex:i] options:nil]; AVAssetTrack *clipVideoTrackB = [[assetClip tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0];

    [timeRanges addObject:[NSValue valueWithCMTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, assetClip.duration)]];
    [tracks addObject:clipVideoTrackB];
}

NSLog(@"HELLO: %@", timeRanges );
[compositionTrack insertTimeRanges:timeRanges ofTracks:tracks atTime:kCMTimeZero error:&error];

AVAssetExportSession *exporter = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:mixComposition presetName:AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality];
// NSParameterAssert(exporter != nil);

NSArray *t; NSString *u;

t = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
u = [t objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *finalPath = [u stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"final.mov"];
NSURL *lastURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:finalPath];
exporter.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;
exporter.outputURL = lastURL;
[exporter exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^(void){
    switch (exporter.status) {
        case AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed:
            NSLog(@"exporting failed");
            [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
            break;
        case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted:
            NSLog(@"exporting completed");
            UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(finalPath, self, nil, NULL);
             [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
            break;
        case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCancelled:
            NSLog(@"export cancelled");
            break;
    }
}];
```

Comment: If you use the debugger to step through this, which line causes the error?

Comment: Did this code ever run on the device? If, yes, you may meanwhile have deleted the resources (movies) and they are still stored on the simulator. May you want to try to clean the project and the build folder and find out, if it still runs on the device.

Comment: and i have tried doing clean build several times.

Comment: Philips this line causes the error

Comment: **[compositionTrack insertTimeRanges:timeRanges ofTracks:tracks atTime:kCMTimeZero error:&error];**

Comment: Running on simulator means your code is bug free but not running on the device means your memory usage is beyond the device capabilities. Please use the memory analyzer to see how much memory  you need.

Comment: Since it's complaining about something being nil, I suggest changing your log message to `NSLog(@"HELLO: %@, %@", timeRanges, tracks);`
and seeing if there's a case where you're passing nil into that call.

Comment: @MahmoudFayez -- Lots of reasons why it might not run on the device.  Too much storage is way down the list.

Comment: Please include the exception "traceback" call stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely your app is using some file that is resident on your Mac but you have not installed and properly addressed on the phone.

But, in any event, log "tracks" as well as well as "timeRanges".

Comment: "tracks" and "timeRanges" do have values. i did NSLog and got the results.    **HELLO: (
    "<AVAssetTrack: 0xdd90e90, trackID = 1, mediaType = vide>",
    "<AVAssetTrack: 0x1d81d250, trackID = 1, mediaType = vide>",
    "<AVAssetTrack: 0xdd40050, trackID = 1, mediaType = vide>"
)
2012-08-21 10:29:17.791 videoTest[382:17903] HELLO: (
    "CMTimeRange: {{0/1 = 0.000}, {14400/600 = 24.000}}",
    "CMTimeRange: {{0/1 = 0.000}, {12000/600 = 20.000}}",
    "CMTimeRange: {{0/1 = 0.000}, {9600/600 = 16.000}}"
)**

Comment: @raman -- Like I said, "Most likely your app is using some file that is resident on your Mac but you have not installed and properly addressed on the phone."   I also said "Please include the exception "traceback" call stack."